# How to get index number in child component when use map func in parent component

Tags: reactjs

```
<tbody>
    {Items.map((item)  => <ItemRow key={item._id} item={item} deleteItem={handleDelete}></ItemRow>) }
 </tbody>
```

How can I send index number to `ItemRow` component  as a props?

Answer (score 1):

Change the map function to have the index and pass it into the ItemRow component via a new prop (I have called idValue):

```
{Items.map((item, index)  => <ItemRow key={item._id} idValue={index} item={item} deleteItem={handleDelete}></ItemRow>) }
```

Based on that ItemRow is your own component, if it's an imported component would have to look at what prop values that component has available to use.